# Seeking help to find $\int \frac{\ln ^2(1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x} d x.$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

**Good News**

Thanks to @Quanto who used dilogarithm function and gave an elegant answer to the integral $$\boxed{\int \ln(1+\sin x)dx= -x\ln2-2 \Im \text{Li}_2(i e^{i x}) }$$
Hence

\begin{align}& \int \frac{\ln ^2(1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x} d x\\
= &2x\ln2+4 \Im \text{Li}_2(i e^{i x})
)-4x+(\tan x-\sec x)\left[(\ln(1+\sin x)+2)^2 +4\right]+C
\end{align}

---

When I met the integral $$\int \frac{\ln ^2(1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x} d x,$$
I first doubted whether it has elementary primitive. Then I tried the simpler one

$$\int \frac{\ln (1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x} d x.$$

I first integrate the denominator for integration by parts

$$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\int \frac{1}{1+\sin x} d x = & \int \frac{1-\sin x}{\cos ^2 x} d x \\= & \int\left(\sec ^2 x-\tan x \sec x\right) d x \\= & \tan x-\sec x+c\end{aligned}\tag*{} $$
Now we can proceed the integration by parts.
$$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}I & =\int \ln (1+\sin x) d(\tan x-\sec x) \\& =(\tan x-\sec x) \ln (1+\sin x)-\int(\tan x-\sec x) \frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x} \\& =\frac{\sin x-1}{\cos x} \ln (1+\sin x)-\int \frac{\sin x-1}{\cos x} \cdot \frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x} d x \\& =\frac{\sin x-1}{\cos x} \ln (1+\sin x)-\int\left(1-\frac{2}{1+\sin x}\right) d x \\& =\frac{\sin x-1}{\cos x} \ln (1+\sin x)-x+2(\tan x-\sec x)+C \\& = (\tan x-\sec x)\left[\ln (1+\sin x)+2\right]-x+C \end{aligned}\tag*{} $$

---

Then I tried the harder one similarly.

**Latest update**

$$
\begin{aligned}&\int \frac{\ln ^2(1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x} d x 
\\= & \int \ln ^2(1+\sin x) d(\tan x-\sec x) \\
= & (\tan x-\sec x) \ln ^2(1+\sin x)+2\int \frac{ \ln (1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x}(1-\sin x) d x\\=& 
(\tan x-\sec x) \ln ^2(1+\sin x)+4 \int \frac{\ln (1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x} d x  -2 \int \ln (1+\sin x) d x \\=& 
(\tan x-\sec x)\left[\left(\ln(1+\sin x)+2)^2+4\right]\right.-4x -2 \int \ln (1+\sin x) d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Then I was stuck by the last integral, the hardest one.

Having no idea, I tried to use the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ for $|x|<1$,

$$
\int \ln (1+\sin x) d x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \int \sin ^k x d x
$$
Using $\sin x= \frac{e^{x i}-e^{-x i}}{2 i}$, we get

$$\int \sin ^{k} x d x=\frac{1}{2 ^k i ^k} \sum_{r=0}^k\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
r
\end{array}\right)(-1)^r\frac{e^{(k-2 r) x i}}{(k-2 r) i}$$

So $$\int \ln (1+\sin x) d x = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^{k-1}}{k2^k} \left[ \sum_{r=0}^k\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
r
\end{array}\right)(-1)^r\frac{e^{(k-2 r) x i}}{k-2 r}\right] +C$$
Now we can conclude that

$$\boxed{\int \frac{\ln ^2(1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x} d x \\ =  
(\tan x-\sec x)\left[\left(\ln(1+\sin x)+2)^2+4\right]\right.-4x
\\+2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^{k-1}}{k2^k} \left[ \sum_{r=0}^k\left(\begin{array}{l}
k \\
r
\end{array}\right)(-1)^r\frac{e^{(k-2 r) x i}}{k-2 r}\right]\right)}$$
which is ugly and not a closed form.

---

Can you help me to find the hardest one $\int \ln (1+\sin x) d x $?

Your suggestion and help are highly appreciated.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+log%281%2Bsin%28x%29%29%5E2%2F%281%2Bsin%28x%29%29) can integrate it, but the result is not “nice” and involves a polylogarithm.

Comment: Thank you for your good news.  Hard-working is needed!

Comment: It is quite challenging.  Finally I was stuck by the integral $\int \ln(1+\sin x)dx.$ Pleas help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the known integral $\int \ln(2\cos t)dt=\frac12\Im \text{Li}_2(-e^{-2i t})
$
and the substitution $x=\frac\pi2-2t$ to obtain
$$J=\int \ln(1+\sin x)dx= -x\ln2-2 \Im \text{Li}_2(i e^{i x})
$$
and, in turn

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{\ln ^2(1+\sin x)}{1+\sin x} d x\\
= &-2J-4x+(\tan x-\sec x)\left[(\ln(1+\sin x)+2)^2 +4\right]
\end{align}

Comment: thank you very much for your elegant solution on the integral involving dilogarithm function.  I learned much from it.

Comment: @Lai - It’s a pleasure

Answer (score 2):

Beside the solution given by Wolfram Alpha, using $x=\sin^{-1}(t)$, we face
$$I=\int \frac{\log ^2(1+\sin (x))}{1+\sin (x)}\,dx=\int \frac{\log ^2(t+1)}{(t+1) \sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$$ which has a solution if we invoke generalized hypergeometric functions (which hides polylogarithm functions).

Mathematica returns
$$-\sqrt{2(t+1)}\,I=16 \,
   _3F_2\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},
   \frac{1}{2};\frac{t+1}{2}\right)+$$ $$\sqrt{2} \log (t+1) \left(4
   \sqrt{t+1} \sin
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t+1}{2}}\right)+\sqrt{1-t}\, (4+\log
   (t+1))\right)$$

From a computational point of view, this requires less effort than what Wolfram Alpha returns.

Comment: Interesting!  Maybe helpful to get the polylogarithm.  Thank you